# Geochart doesn't take any color

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, dom-events

I wonder why geochart doesn't take any color from my code (take color value from Google sheet), not even defaultColor or colorAxis as you can see in the line that commented out,I have tried that all but it doesn't work.

The data in the Google sheet look like this:

[image]

Hope someone can help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>


<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        #colormap path:hover { fill: #90db7c; }
        #colormap rect:hover {fill:transparent;}
</style>
     
     
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['geochart']});
    
// Callback that draws
function drawRegionsMap() { 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTfxVvfDKn6iXn4W_m7HJ_86JOGNDsxYSSaXipEo0vM/edit#gid=0');
      // query.setQuery('select A,B,C');
    query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
}
    
function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
        }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
        
    var colorValues = [];
    var numRows = data.getNumberOfRows();
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
          colorValues.push(parseInt(data.getValue(i, 6)));
    }
            
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    //show data in tooltips
    view.setColumns([0,{
                type:'string',
                label : 'dataname',
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                        var dt1 = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1)
                        var dt2 = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2)
                        var url = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 4)
                        var image = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
                        //colorValues.push(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6))
                return dt1 + " - " + dt2 
          },
            role: 'tooltip',
                p: {html: true}
    }]);


    
    //assign color to colorValues
    var colorNames = [];
    colorValues.forEach(function(value) {
            if (value <= 2) {
          colorNames.push('red');
                //alert('red');
        } else if ((value > 2) && (value <= 4)) {
          colorNames.push('yellow');
                //alert('yellow');
        } else {
          colorNames.push('green');
                //alert('green');
          }
    });
    
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('colormap'));
     
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
          var selection = chart.getSelection();
          if (selection.length > 0) {
            //console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4));
                    window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4));
          }
    }); 
        
        // Set options for the chart.
    
   var options = {
       defaultcolor: 'yellow'
            //title:'WEEE',  
        //colorAxis: {
              //  values: [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6],
            //  colors: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange' ,'red','purple','lightblue'],
          //    };
            //colors: colorNames,
            //values: colorValues
      //    },
        
            //backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
            //backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            //datalessRegionColor: '#F5F0E7',
            //displayMode: 'regions', 
            //enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
            //resolution: 'countries',
            //sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
            //region:'world',
            //keepAspectRatio: true,
            //width:800,
            //height:600,
            //tooltip: {isHtml:'true',textStyle: {color: '#444444'} }   
   // };
}
    chart.draw(view, options);

}


// Draw the chart when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id='colormap'></div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this? --> [coloring your chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#coloring-your-chart)

Comment: @WhiteHat I have seen that,what's wrong with my value? (1-6) is that not correct?

Comment: see the [data format for regions mode](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format) -- data table needs two columns, (1) region location, (2) a number that corresponds to the `values` in the `colorAxis`...

Comment: @WhiteHat I don't get it,I have region location in the first column and number value for color in the last column,and join another column in Dataview cause the chart not allow more than 2 columns.Does it mean that I have to join colors column in Dataview as well?or the colorAxis will get the data from Datatable only and need to have only 2 columns?

Comment: need two columns for geo chart, first with location, second with number value of color -- try view like this --> `view.setColumns([0,6]);`

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks so much.It's working now